# Add elements to existing jQuery set

Tags: javascript, jquery

Considering we have

```
let existingSet = $();
```

How are `newElements` added to that set by means of jQuery?

```
existingSet = existingSet.add(newElements);
```

is not an option, because I need the reference to this object. As well as `$.extend`, because `existingSet` may not be empty.

[$.merge](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/) documentation says that it accepts array-likes, but provides no further explanation of that, I'm not sure if it is suitable for jQuery objects.

Comment: _"...is not an option, because I need the reference to this object"_ - What exactly do you mean by this? According to the docs, this should work for what you're asking

Comment: @War10ck I already passed the reference to existingSet somewhere, and I need to keep this object instead of creating another.

Comment: @estus To my knowledge, you cannot add items to an existing set like that, it will always create a new one.  What you can do however is instead of passing around your initial set, instead pass an object that contains your set. `aSet = {set: $()};` Then you can update the reference, `aSet.set = aSet.set.add( newElement )`, and use it anywhere that has a reference to aSet.  I'm not sure how you're trying to use this, but obviously any operations you ran on the old set (event binding, etc.) will not automatically use the new set.

Comment: @Waxen Thanks, this is the workaround, but I really hope it can be done in more straightforward way. Currently, I'm trying 'newElements.each' in conjunction with 'existingSet.push', which is a bit lame, and I'm conscious of the pitfalls, $ objects are array-likes, not arrays.

Answer (score -2):

why not use prepend to add to beginning of set, and append to add new elements to end of set ?

```
$(myset).append('<div>New element here</div>')
```

or

```
$(myset).prepend('<div>New element here</div>')
```

Comment: "Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements". It is certainly not what I want to do.